# Differentiation - maximising perimeter - Are the answers wrong?

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, optimization

The question in the photo asks to prove that $ x = y $ for the maximum perimeter. I was struggling to do this (although I eventually created a nice proof using sine and cosine - this is written in the given space).

[image: Question (and my answer)]

The answers seem to assume that you can just substitute in the circle equation into $y$ when $x$ and $y$ in this case are lengths, not coordinates. Am I wrong about this?

[image: Answer Page]

Comment: $\angle ACB=90^\circ$ because of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle). That is why they can use Pythagoras' theorem. And, the 64 there is $64=8^2$. So that step looks OK to me.

Comment: Oh now I see! I forgot about that 90 degree rule. Thanks! Do you want to post that as ananswer?

Comment: The question wants an algebraic/differential proof, so I would not get any marks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\angle ACB=90^\circ$ because of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle). That is why they can use Pythagoras' theorem. Moreover, $64=8^2$.

**Note** It might be easier to solve this question without differentiation, if one is aware of the Cauchy inequality
$$
ax+by\leq \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.
$$
The perimiter is given by
$$
8+x+y=8+1\cdot x+1\cdot y\leq8+\sqrt{1^2+1^2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=8+\sqrt{2}\cdot8.
$$
Moreover, equality in the Cauchy inequality appears when $ay-bx=0$. In this case, when $y=x$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, since, $\angle ACB=90^\circ$ hence in right $\triangle ACB$ $$AB^2=AC^2+BC^2$$$$8^2=x^2+y^2\implies y=\sqrt{64-x^2}$$ 
hence, the perimeter of $\triangle ABC$ $$P=AB+BC+AC=8+x+y$$
setting the value of $y$, $$P=x+\sqrt{64-x^2}+8$$
differentiating $P$ w.r.t. $x$, $$\frac{dP}{dx}=1+\frac{-x}{\sqrt{64-x^2}}$$
$$\frac{d^2P}{dx^2}=-\frac{64}{(64-x^2)^{3/2}}<0$$
thus, the perimeter is maximum.

Now, for maximum $\frac{dP}{dx}=0$, hence $$1+\frac{-x}{\sqrt{64-x^2}}=0\implies x=4\sqrt 2$$
$$\implies y=\sqrt{64-32}=4\sqrt 2$$ since, for maximum perimeter $x=y=4\sqrt 2$

hence,  $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles triangle if the perimeter is maximum

The maximum perimeter of $\triangle ABC$ $$P_{max}=x+y+8=4\sqrt 2+4\sqrt 2+8=\color{red}{8(\sqrt 2+1)}$$